# CakePHP less than or equal to a variable

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In CakePHP to do an equal to or less than statment you do this,

```
'conditions' => array('Model.field <=' => $variable)
```

However, i don't know how to do it with the variable on the other side of the condition,

```
'conditions' => array($variable<= =>'Model.field')
```

As you can imagine this doesn't work and i don't know what to do.

I am confused and annoyed at how to get this to work

Comment: why do you want to do this? you can't do variable as a key and field as a value in cakephp. Do you want to do greater than or equal to?

Comment: `$variable.' <=' => 'Model.field'`?